# How to load data from server in a background before launch properly

Tags: ios, swift, fetch, nsurl

I'm dealing with such problem: I have to fetch from server data and bind it to my pickerView. But now, on the first launch I get empty picker, as function for retrieving executes after viewDidLoad()

So, can I somehow fetch data before viewDidLoad()?

I've tried to use DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async for retrieving data, but it looks like it done in improper way.

```
var currencies = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setDelegates()
    setupLabelInPicker()
    updatePickerInfoBeforeStart()
}

func updatePickerInfoBeforeStart() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.retrieveCurrency{ [weak self]
            currencies in self?.currencies = currencies
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.pickerTo.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }
}
```

Methods for retrieve data:

```
func retrieveCurrency(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    requestCurrencyRates { [unowned self] (data, error) in

        if error != nil {
            fatalError()
        } else {
             comletion(self.parseCurrensyResponse(data: data))
        }
    }
}
```

Binding data to picker:

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return currencies[row]
}
```

Are there exist common approach for such tasks?

Comment: Why not show some sort of loading screen meanwhile service is being called ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IMO you can do this with below approaches:**

**1)Fetch required data at app launch**

You can create a **dummy splash screen** with exact UI as in your launch `storyboard` and there you can fetch your `data` from server.Later you will just have to pass this data to the `pickerView` whenever required.

**2)If you just need in a particular ViewController**

In this case you can fetch the `data` from server in the `viewController` itself.You can show a loader meanwhile you fetch the data.